# How do I get today's date automatically as an integer in python

Tags: python-2.7

I want to write a code where it returns user's age when user enters his age in YYYYmmdd format. I have noticed that error lies in the line when I need to get the today's date as an integer but cannot convert strftime to an integer. I am using python 2.7 Any help? thanks!

```
import datetime

class User(object):

    def __init__(self, full_name, birthday):
        self.full_name = full_name
        self.birthday =  birthday

    def calculate_age(self):
        """Return the age"""

        yyyy = int(self.birthday[0:4])
        mm = int(self.birthday[4:6])
        dd = int(self.birthday[6:8])           
        dob = datetime.date(yyyy, mm, dd)                              
        today = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
        today = int(today)

        age_in_days =  (today - dob)

        age_in_years = age_in_days / 365
        return int(age_in_years)

def main():
  user_enter = raw_input("Enter your b'day:")
  User1 = User("susa", user_enter)  
  print ("your age is" + User1.calculate_age())

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of going to all the trouble of converting things to `int`, you can calculate the difference between two `date` objects and obtain the result's number of days:

```
...
dob = datetime.date(yyyy, mm, dd)
today = datetime.datetime.today().date()
age_in_days = (today - dob).days
...
```

---

Also, there as some extra things that you can consider reviewing in your code:

- Your print is trying to concatenate a `string` with an `int` and it won't work.
  You can cast the `calculate_age()` result to fix this:

  `print("your age is " + str(User1.calculate_age()))`
- You can use [strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to convert your birthday string input to `datetime` 
  and you can call `date()` to convert your `datetime` to `date`. This way you can avoid having to manually breaking your string into parts:

  `dob = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.birthday, '%Y%m%d').date()`